# How to get request path in beast::websocket

Tags: beast-websockets

I have the following beast::websocket example working: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/

Starting from that code, and assuming that I want to distinguish a request from a client like this:

ws://mydomain.com/some_operation?channel=XXX

...from a request like this other

ws://mydomain.com/some_other_operation?channel=YYY

How can I access the request path sended by the client?

Comment: Did you find out what the solution was in the end? I need the same. Currently thinking to use a request decorator but not sure of that works on the server side